# MVC 3 not routing some URL's

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, asp.net-routing

I am developing an MVC 3 that has some custom routes defined. All routes work great locally (using IIS Express and Cassini) but when I push the site to my production server one of the routes bombs with a 404.

Local setup:
Windows 7
VS 2010 SP1
IIS Express

Production setup:
Windows Server 2008 Datacenter
IIS 7.5

The route that is bombing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "ShortLinks",
      "E-{id}",
      new { Controller = "Public", Action = "ResolveShortLink" },
      new[] { "namespace.WebUI.Controllers" }
    );

  routes.MapRoute(
      "SmsShortLinks",
      "T-{id}",
      new { Controller = "Public", Action = "ResolveShortLink" },
      new[] { "namespace.WebUI.Controllers" }
    );
```

An example request looks like the following.

http://domain/E-7d9cbaa2-25b0-47be-8b2c-31844a3de482
http://domain/T-7d9cbaa2-25b0-47be-8b2c-31844a3de482

Again when I run this locally the routing works perfectly but when I push it to the production server it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look to see what route it's actually going to? I suggest having a read of this 
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx
or 
use Glimpse to see what route is actually being resolved, it might help shed some light on the problem... 
http://getglimpse.com/

Comment: Great tools, unfortunately they do not shed any more light on my issue. The routing debugger simply tells me that it is falling through my defined route and hitting the default one.

Comment: Ok so the strangest thing has happened, these routes auto-magically begin working after I disabled the routing debugger. Not sure what resolved the issue unfortunately and due to deadlines will have to make note of it and return later for a post mortem.